# Avoid losing focus on select

Tags: html, css

I have a form in a div with a small height. On hovering the div it's expanding and a dropdown selector appears. There are items of the dropdown that are not in the div area, when I click them the div minimizes. How can I make css/js to hold it open, while selecting on dropdown menu? It should not minimize when an item is clicked in select menu.

Edit: If there isn't any css solution I will accept javascript / jquery too.

HTML:

```
<div class="formcontainer">    
    <form>
        <span>hover me</span><br/>
        <select name="Type" id="field2-A4318">
            <option id="field2-1-A4318" value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option id="field2-2-A4318" value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option id="field2-3-A4318" value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option id="field2-4-A4318" value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option id="field2-4-A4318" value="5" selected="selected">Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.formcontainer{
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 25px 10px 10px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(100,100,100,0.2);
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
}


.formcontainer:hover, .formcontainer:active, .formcontainer:focus{
    height: auto;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dCpa3/2/

Comment: When do you want it to minimise then? If you want it to stay open you will have to use javascript to change the css properties of the div.formcontainer

Comment: as in css, when none of the elements inside .formcontainer has a focus, active or hover

Comment: but it is doing that... I am using firefox & it is working. It minimises only when I click on a select item

Comment: that's what I want to avoid, it should not minimize when select item is clicked.

Comment: So then use javascript - like I said

Comment: if there isn't any css solution I will accept javascript / jquery too.

Comment: @abimelex You can check my CSS solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is a **CSS only solution**:

```
#field2-A4318 {
    display: none;
}

.formcontainer:hover #field2-A4318,
#field2-A4318:focus {
    display: block; 
}
```

Just keep it simple. No need to mess with heights and overflow elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/dCpa3/10/

Answer (score 4):

Adding this jQuery code does the magic:

```
$('#field2-A4318').click( function(){
    $('.formcontainer').css('min-height','30px');
    $('.formcontainer').css('height','auto');
});
```

[Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/dCpa3/4/)

Comment: looks good, but I think I need to add a timer to minimize it som how again automatically...